# Use any() command in Python if statement

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to write an `if` statement in Python that iterates over the rows of a DataFrame. If that row meets one of several possible conditions, it does a calculation. My MWE is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

coin = ['a','b','c'] # conditions

xlist = pd.DataFrame() # data
xlist['col1'] = np.array(['a','j','k','b','b','d','c','a']) # state
xlist['col2'] = np.array([1,2,2,1,2,0,1,3])

for ii in range(len(xlist)):

    if any(coin in xlist['col1'][ii]):
        # if state meets a condition, do calculation x
        print('result 1')
    else:
        # if state doesn't meet condition, do calculation y
        print('result 2')
```

I keep getting an error:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

so this isn't the correct Python way of doing it. What am I doing wrong with the `any` statement?

The output should be:

```
result 1
result 2
result 2
result 1
result 1
result 2
result 1
result 1
```

Comment: `any()` just doesn't do what you want to achieve there. You're looking for an intersection between two sets.

Comment: You shouldn't be using dataframes like this at all to begin with

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga. this is a MWE, my original problem involves dataframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your condition is wrong. Instead of `any(coin in xlist['col1'][ii])`, try `xlist['col1'][ii] in coin`:

```py
for ii in range(len(xlist)):
    if xlist['col1'][ii] in coin:
        # if state meets a condition, do calculation x
        print('result 1')
    else:
        # if state doesn't meet condition, do calculation y
        print('result 2')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
In [846]: l = np.where(xlist['col1'].isin(coin), 'result 1', 'result 2')

In [847]: l # numpy array
Out[847]: 
array(['result 1', 'result 2', 'result 2', 'result 1', 'result 1',
       'result 2', 'result 1', 'result 1'], dtype='<U8')

In [848]: l.tolist() # list
Out[848]: 
['result 1',
 'result 2',
 'result 2',
 'result 1',
 'result 1',
 'result 2',
 'result 1',
 'result 1']
```